# OpenWhisk action fails on local Ubuntu deployment

Tags: ubuntu, openwhisk

I deployed OpenWhisk on a local Ubuntu machine according to the following documentation: https://github.com/openwhisk/openwhisk/blob/master/tools/ubuntu-setup/README.md. However, when I try to invoke sample action with command:

```
wsk action invoke /whisk.system/utils/echo -p message hello --blocking --result
```

I get the following error:

```
Unable to invoke action ‘utils/echo’: Post 
https://172.17.0.1/api/v1/namespaces/whisk.system/actions/utils/echo?  
blocking=true: dial tcp 172.17.0.1:443: getsockopt: connection refused.
```

I set my apihost to 172.17.0.1 (Docker edge host) and I’m using guest namespace with authentication from ansible/files/auth.guest. I suppose that some services should run in the Docker so that it’ll listen on the 443 port, but I have no idea what services and why are they not running.

I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: check if `nginx` is up and running via `docker ps` - do you see `nginx` listed?

Comment: It has status 'Restarting _N_ ago'.

Comment: I checked and the container raports such an error: 
`nginx: [emerg] open() "/etc/nginx/nginx.conf" failed (2: No such file or directory)`

Comment: I figured out that everytime I reboot the host, Docker containers with NGINX, Registrator and Consul can't switch to "UP" state. I thought it was beacuse I deployed OpenWhisk from regular account. However, when I did that from root the result is the same and I don't know why.

Comment: I strongly suspect it's an instance of this defect https://github.com/openwhisk/openwhisk/issues/32